# Wordpress: show the name of the blog in the browser

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change the display in the browser. When you are at the front page of the website, the name of the blog is written in the browser. But if you leave the front page and switch to another page, the name of the current page will be shown in the browser. I would like to fix the name of blog for every single page. 
I couldn't find a title-tag in the functions.php nor could I find something about the title in the header.php. Do you have any idea what the problem is? Do you know what I mean? Thank you very much.

Greetings,
pradhana

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ install this it will help you SEO and title also

Comment: Ok, it works. Thank you.